# JSON Custom Item Models (1.14) : First Person and Third Person Scale, Rotation, and Translation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I've been trying for the last few hours and I can't get the right values for the `scale`, `rotation`, and `translation` of the custom item in the json file. I want the *size, rotation, and location* of the items on the screen to be exactly like their parent item.

```
{
  "parent": "builtin/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "item/custom_sword"
  },
  "display": {
    "firstperson_righthand": {
      "scale": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    },
    "firstperson_lefthand": {
      "scale": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    },
    "thirdperson_righthand": {
      "scale": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    },
    "thirdperson_lefthand": {
      "scale": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some pictures of what I mean:

[image: Examples of current and desired effect]

I need some help for the right values to put in `scale`, `rotation`, and `translation`.

Comment: What do you mean by "you know the right values?" Do you want someone to provide the values that allow the items to look a certain way? I believe that depends on how your item models are constructed?

Comment: I edited it now, hoping you could understand it better. Yes, I want someone to provide the values that allow the items to look exactly like their parent item. I did not use any 3D and complex models for the custom items. It's just recolored texture.

Comment: You're looking for the vanilla values of the vanilla items, then? Can't you find them by disabling alls mods of your Minecraft installation and checking the appropriate .json file?

Comment: Somewhere you could probably find the rotation, scale, and translation for the diamond sword. Copying the data from the diamond sword, you could probably find the correct values from the sword.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this as off-topic?

Comment: Yeah, I doubt the answer is what Robomike wants, but it's absolutely on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As this did not have an answer, I had to figure it out myself through trial and error. The values seem to be:

Edit: after like two hours of trying out different values, refreshing my pack, swapping hands to compare it to an existing sword, and repeating... I realized Blockbench has a "default weapon" preset...

Anyways here you go:

```
"display": {
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [0, -90, 55],
            "translation": [0, 4, 0.5],
            "scale": [0.85, 0.85, 0.85]
        },
        "thirdperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [0, 90, -55],
            "translation": [0, 4, 0.5],
            "scale": [0.85, 0.85, 0.85]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [0, -90, 25],
            "translation": [1.13, 3.2, 1.13],
            "scale": [0.68, 0.68, 0.68]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [0, 90, -25],
            "translation": [1.13, 3.2, 1.13],
            "scale": [0.68, 0.68, 0.68]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using Blockbench (https://blockbench.net/), I use it every time for my models.

Comment: So what are the values then?